# WordPress: insert char in between two menu items

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working on my custom wordpress theme and i'm having struggle designing the first menu in the header the way i want.

So, in the header.php I'm inserting the menu in this way, so that the links are not surrounded by table tags:

```
    <?php 
          $menuParameters = array(
              'container'         =>  false,
              'echo'              =>  false,
              'items_wrap'        =>  '%3$s',
              'depth'             =>  0,
          );
          $output = strip_tags(wp_nav_menu($menuParameters), '<a>');
          //This is my first try with regex, but i didnt manage to
          //only insert the character in between two links and not
          //one at the and as well.
          //$output = Preg_replace( "(\n)", "$0|\r\n", $output);
          echo $output;
    ?>
```

So this code gives me a menu that looks like this:

```
    <a href="http://localhost/page-1/">Page 1</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/page-2/">Page 2</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/page-3/">Page 3</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/page-4/">Page 4</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/page-5/">Page 5</a>
```

Just for the understanding, this is what output i want to get:

```
    <a href="http://localhost/page-1/">Page 1</a>
    |
    <a href="http://localhost/page-2/">Page 2</a>
    |
    <a href="http://localhost/page-3/">Page 3</a>
    |
    <a href="http://localhost/page-4/">Page 4</a>
    |
    <a href="http://localhost/page-5/">Page 5</a>
```

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Is this what you want? `function pipe($url)
{
    return preg_replace('/(<\/a>)(<a)/', '$1 | $2', $url);
}

echo pipe('<a href="abc">Link 1</a><a href="abc">Link 2</a>');`

Comment: well, that does kind of the right thing with only two links but when i pass $output from the example above to the pipe function it won't work at all.

Comment: `...with only two links...` - obviously you haven't tested it because it does work for multiple links not only two! You are given an example to start developing on so it is up to you to adjust it to your needs. Remove new line breaks from your links and pass it to function. It will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_nav_menu()` allows the arguments `after` and `link_after` to add text either after the link text or the link markup, so you could update your parameters:

```
$menuParameters = array(
          'container'         =>  false,
          'echo'              =>  false,
          'items_wrap'        =>  '%3$s',
          'depth'             =>  0,
          'after'             => "<span>|</span>"
);
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

EDIT: If you don't want to show a seperator after the last link, you could use some CSS pseudo-elements:

```
.mymenu span:last-child{ display: none; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k593ezoL/1

Comment: yeah thats almost what i want except for after the last link, i don't want the "|" to be inserted.. how could i achieve this ?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Okay, i did it by adding this `$output = Preg_replace( "(\|\Z)", "", $output);`

Comment: `preg_replace` is rather costly and doesn't need to be used for styling purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://localhost/page-1/">Page 1</a><a href="http://localhost/page-2/">Page 2</a><a href="http://localhost/page-3/">Page 3</a><a href="http://localhost/page-4/">Page 4</a><a href="http://localhost/page-5/">Page 5</a>
```

Comment: Describe what you have been added and why?